# How do you make sure a data page can only have 3 rows

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, size

For a table with a setting of `(fillfactor = 75)` I am trying to make sure that each data page can only have 3 rows.

```
select ((8192 * 0.75 - 24) / 3)- 4 - 24;  -- returns 2012.
```

First 24 is page header meta byte.
Last 24 is t_hoff (row meta bytes for every row)
Last 4 is the line pointer for each inserted row.
2012 % 8 = 4. So I guess to make sure one page has only 3 rows I can only use 2008 byte?

```
CREATE TABLE hot (hotid int,s char(2000))WITH (fillfactor = 75,autovacuum_enabled = OFF);
INSERT INTO hot VALUES (1, 'A');
SELECT
    lp,lp_off,lp_len,t_hoff,t_ctid,t_infomask::bit(16),t_infomask2    
FROM
    heap_page_items (get_raw_page ('hot', 0));
```

returns

```
 lp | lp_off | lp_len | t_hoff | t_ctid |    t_infomask    | t_infomask2
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+-------------
  1 |   6160 |   2032 |     24 | (0,1)  | 0000100000000010 |           2
(1 row)
```

My guess of  why **lp_len = 2032**. 2032 = 8 + 2000 + 24.
first  4 byte int paddling it to 8 bytes. 2000 is for column `s`, the last 24 bytes are row meta page bytes.

For the following table I expected `lp_len` to be 2032. But it's not. What did I miss?

```
CREATE TABLE hot_test (
    hotid int,    hotid1 int,s char(2000)
)WITH (fillfactor = 75,autovacuum_enabled = OFF);
INSERT INTO hot_test    VALUES (1, 1, 'A');

SELECT
    lp,lp_off,lp_len,t_hoff,t_ctid,t_infomask::bit(16),t_infomask2    
FROM
    heap_page_items (get_raw_page ('hot_test', 0));
```

returns

```
 lp | lp_off | lp_len | t_hoff | t_ctid |    t_infomask    | t_infomask2
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+-------------
  1 |   8128 |     59 |     24 | (0,1)  | 0000100000000010 |           3
(1 row)
```

Update:

```
drop table hot_test;
CREATE TABLE hot_test (
    hotid int,    hotid1 int,s char(1999)
)WITH (fillfactor = 75,autovacuum_enabled = OFF);
ALTER TABLE hot_test ALTER s SET STORAGE PLAIN;
INSERT INTO hot_test    VALUES (1, 1, 'A');

SELECT
    lp,lp_off,lp_len,t_hoff,t_ctid,t_infomask::bit(16),t_infomask2    
FROM
    heap_page_items (get_raw_page ('hot_test', 0));
```

returns

```
 lp | lp_off | lp_len | t_hoff | t_ctid |    t_infomask    | t_infomask2
----+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------------+-------------
  1 |   6152 |   2035 |     24 | (0,1)  | 0000100000000010 |           3
(1 row)
```

2035 = 4 + 4 + 1999 + 4 + 24
So I guess varlena text needs 4 bytes of padding?

```
drop table paddling;
CREATE TABLE paddling (
    hotid int,    hotid1 int,s char(127)
)WITH (fillfactor = 75,autovacuum_enabled = OFF);
ALTER TABLE paddling ALTER s SET STORAGE PLAIN;
INSERT INTO paddling    VALUES (1, 1, 'ASDFGHJKLQWERTYUI');
SELECT
    lp,lp_off,lp_len,lp_len - 24 - 8,t_hoff,t_ctid,t_infomask::bit(16),t_infomask2    
FROM
    heap_page_items (get_raw_page ('paddling', 0));
```

returns

```
 lp | lp_off | lp_len | ?column? | t_hoff | t_ctid |    t_infomask    | t_infomask2
----+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------------+-------------
  1 |   8024 |    163 |      131 |     24 | (0,1)  | 0000100000000010 |           3
(1 row)
```

```
drop table paddling;
CREATE TABLE paddling (
    hotid int,    hotid1 int,s char(126)
)WITH (fillfactor = 75,autovacuum_enabled = OFF);
ALTER TABLE paddling ALTER s SET STORAGE PLAIN;
INSERT INTO paddling    VALUES (1, 1, 'ASDFGHJKLQWERTYUI');

SELECT
    lp,lp_off,lp_len,lp_len - 24 - 8,t_hoff,t_ctid,t_infomask::bit(16),t_infomask2    
FROM
    heap_page_items (get_raw_page ('paddling', 0));
```

returns

```
 lp | lp_off | lp_len | ?column? | t_hoff | t_ctid |    t_infomask    | t_infomask2
----+--------+--------+----------+--------+--------+------------------+-------------
  1 |   8032 |    159 |      127 |     24 | (0,1)  | 0000100000000010 |           3
(1 row)
```

Seems for `char(x)`, if x <= 126, padding is one byte. x > 126 then padding is 4 byte. Tested, also applies to `text` data type.

Comment: Why do you care that *only* three rows fit on a page?

Comment: https://habr.com/en/companies/postgrespro/articles/483768/ I was leanring this post. @RonJohn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html). For rows in excess of a certain size threshold (which you crossed in your second example), large attributes will be compressed before storage.

If you really want to avoid this optimization, disable TOAST:

```
ALTER TABLE hot_test ALTER s SET STORAGE PLAIN;
```

Comment: now lp_len is 2036. I thought it would be 2032 (24 + 8+2000). Can you further explain it.

Comment: It is simply padding.